# How to show the name of the picture in the gallery by clicking on it?

Tags: android, android-gallery

How to show the name of the picture in the gallery by clicking on it?

i made an array of my images and I get the / sdcard / CameraExample / 28.06.2011_11-23-54.bmp, but it displays only 1 of 17. I would like to know how to remove a directory file, leaving only its name. and how do I assign getname each picture in the array?

it's my sample code.

```
 Gallery g = (Gallery) findViewById(R.id.Gallery01);  
g.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(this, ReadSDCard()));  

final TextView label2 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.TextView01);

final TextView label = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);
label.setText("Фото 0 из" + g.getAdapter().getCount());

g.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {  
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent,  
      View v, int position, long id)  {


        label.setText("Фото"+" "+ ++position + " из " + parent.getCount());

        String dirPath = "/sdcard/CameraExample/";
        File f = new File(dirPath);
        File[] files = f.listFiles();


        for(int i=0; i < files.length; i++)
        {
            File file = files[i];
            String fileName = file.getName();
            if (i == position)
            {

            label2.setText(fileName);
            }




        }

    }
});
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dude you should be setting the name of the file in the label instead of setting its postion.

Check your code over here:

```
label.setText("Photo" + ++position + " of " + parent.getCount() + file);
```

Modify this to as:-

```
String fileName = file.getName();
label.setText("Viewing file: " + fileName);
```

This should work for you.